# Ответ дублирует данный ранее ответ

Tags: обсуждение

Как быть если пользователь оставил ответ, ранее данный?

В некоторых случаях я видел данный слово-в-слово, полную копипасту, но в принципе, есть случаи и когда ответ является подмножеством ранее данного.

Например:

- полный дубликат [Css html. Как сделать круглый пунктирный див как шкала. Пример на картинке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1015189/213987)
- неполный дубликат [Как выйти из редактора Vi или Vim?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437417/213987)

Вероятно, в случае полной копипасты ответ-дубль (более поздний) можно просто удалить?

Comment: Это не дубль ответа...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ответы полные дубли тоже были в районе пары-тройки недель, попробую поискать.

Comment: @Qwertiy В комментарии не хватает эпилога - "_не дубль ответа_, потому, что ... ".

Comment: @0xdb, потому что он короткий, а некоторым нравятся короткие ответы точно и по делу.

Comment: Дубли ответов стоит удалять. Неполные дубли, если в них есть какие-то уточнения или дополнения, не стоит удалять

Answer (score 4):

Полная копипаста называется "плагиат" и запрещена лицензией CC-BY-SA (всеми версиями). Но даже если предположить, что автор ответа написал всё то же самое независимо (что возможно для небольших ответов, но нереально для подробных) - ничего нового ответ-дубль сайту не даёт. Мусор надо удалять.

Неполный же дубликат может оказаться, при некоторых условиях, понятнее оригинала, а потому безусловно мусорным не является. Оценивать неполные дубликаты следует как обычные ответы.